# Python Rewriting a code that returns a dictionary containing statistics

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i have a function here that is suppose to returning a dict containing what happens when the program runs. I cannot post the full program because I could get in trouble but I wrote this code that I know works for my program and I was wondering if it could be different in a simpler way taking up less lines or a longer way.

```
def start(self, startingevents):
    """Run the simulation on list of events in <startingevents>.

    Return a dict containing statistics of the simulation.
    @type self: Simulation
    @type initial_events: list[Event]
        An initial list of events.
    @rtype: dict[str, object]
    """
    eventcount = []

    for event in startingevents:
        eventcount.add(event)

    for event in eventcount:
        new_events = event.do(self.dispatcher, self.monitor)
        for new_event in new_events:
            eventcount.add(new_event)
    return self._monitor.report()
```

Comment: That returns a list, not a dict.

Comment: @JohnGordon fixed it the last line though is part of the program and it would return a dict.

Comment: Your `for event in eventcount:...eventcount.add(new_event)` lines could be simplified to `[eventcount.add(new_event) for event in eventcount for new_event in event.do(self.dispatcher, self.monitor)]`

Comment: Belongs on overview.stackexchange.com, not here

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, whether it will do the thing, but it might be worth to give it a try:

```
eventcount = [  new_element
                for event in startingevents
                for new_element in event.do(self.dispatcher, self.monitor)
             ]
```

instead of all `for` loops